# Why is code not highlighted and snippets not runnable after an edit?

Tags: feature-request, bug, stack-snippets, syntax-highlighting, code

When a post that contains code is edited and I click on the "An edit has been made to this post" link above it, I can see the edited post, but the code will not be highlighted unless I refresh the page.

The same thing goes for HTML/CSS/JS snippets, the code will not be highlighted and the snippet can't be executed (the footer that contains the buttons doesn't show up) unless the page is refreshed.

I think this causes a bit of an irritation especially when dealing with a lot of posts at the same time.